# Editing user links in header

Tags: magento-1.9, template

Hey guys I'm new to the Magento platform and just installed CED CsMarketplace multi vendor module. I'd like to edit the "I am a Vendor" button so that it says something else because it sounds just terrible.  I can't for the life of me find where to edit that navigation button though.  I know where to find the others, but not that one..

[image: nav links magento]

Bonus question, how can I make it only appear if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through the layout system. In your theme you should have your `local.xml` or `theme.xml`. You should be able to find something like the following for the i am a vender link:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
    <label>My Account</label>
    <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
    <title>My Account</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>10</position>
</action>
```

see `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml`

To only add the link when customers are logged in you could use the reference of `customer_logged_in` e.g:

```
<customer_logged_in>
  <reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">                                
     <label>I am a Vendor</label>
     <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
     <title>Log Out</title>
     <prepare/>
     <urlParams/>
     <position>100</position>
    </action>
  </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```